# Fourier Series for a Dirac Train

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, dirac-delta

I'm trying to find out by myself the Fourier Series of a Dirac Train, but I'm getting after Integration by Parts that Dn equals to 0 and not to 1 as needed to be. Could you please help me find my mistake?

`So, given`:

$x(t)$$=$$\Sigma$$Dn$$e$$^{i{\omega}nt}$

`Whilst`:

$x(t)$$=$$\Sigma$$\delta$$(n)$

`I'm finding out the` $Dn$ *`(I cut some obvious equations here)`*:

$Dn=1/P{\int}{\delta}(n)e^{-i{\omega}nt}=$

*`And now I'm getting to trouble...`*

`Here I do integration by parts.`

`From:`

${\int}f'(t)g(t)=f(t)g(t) - {\int}f(t)g'(t)$

`We get the following, by assuming that` $f'(t)={\delta}(t)$, `which gives us that` $f(t)={\int}{\delta}(t)=1$ :

${\int}{\delta}(n){e}^{-i{\omega}{n}{t}} = 1*{e^{-i{\omega}nt}}-{\int}{1*-i{\omega}nt*e^{-i{\omega}nt}} = 1*{e^{-i{\omega}nt}}+i{\omega}nt*{\int}e^{-i{\omega}nt} = 1*{e^{-i{\omega}nt}}-i{\omega}nt/i{\omega}nt*{e^{-i{\omega}nt}}= 1*{e^{-i{\omega}nt}} - 1*{e^{-i{\omega}nt}} = 0$

`Where is my mistake?`

Comment: Why do you do integration by parts when evaluating a $\delta$-integral? Use the defining property $\int \delta(x)f(x){\rm d}x = f(0)$.

Comment: @Winther Is it true by definition? If so, cool it resolves my equation :) Thanks! P.S I did it because ${\delta}(0)$ is infinity :( `EDIT:` I'm still confused, why can't I do that what I did...

Comment: Ok got it... Approximately. I don't know yet what my mistake is, but what @Winther said is a result of estimation for calculating such integral, using something named as Lebesgue Integration.... But if someone will be able to point out my mistake and tell me what's in real life is incorrect in my question, so I can understand it, it'd be glad for any other or additional explanation. Many thanks ahead to anyone who's participating!

Comment: The delta function is not a normal function. It is must often defined via how it operates under an integral sign (the expression I gave). When you do integration by parts you get $\int e^{-iwnt}{\rm d}n$ you evaluate this as if it were a normal integral. This integral is divergent in the normal sense, however as a distribution it is another expression for $\delta(x)$ and with the prefactor it roughy becomes $x\delta(x)$ which is zero. So it's possible to get the right result your way, but you have to know what you can and cannot do with distributions.

Comment: All this can be confusing till you learned more. In the meantime whenever you have a $\delta$-function in the integrand just remember the definition I gave above and you will be able to write down the answer immediately. (And for more info try to start by reading the discussion on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function which also lists several definitions)

Comment: @Winther thanks! Yes I will use that formula, meanwhile I found an answer to my question and why I cannot integrate by parts. It's because of the graphic visual represntation of integrating by parts. I wrote answer below, it's becaue in visual form we substract parts and here the part is infinity minus infinity.

Comment: Well no. The actual answer is that you are missing the basic understanding for how these kinds of 'functions' and integrals are defined and work. It's quite common and the problem is with the teaching of this (but its hard to do it any other way as the theory is complicated and one is usually more interested in applications). You are told to treat these kinds of integrals as normal integrals. They are not, but they act (can be treated) as normal integrals in many respects. You just need to know how to handle them.

Comment: oh okay, so I belive this is a case where I see only part of the Iceberg. The important part for me is clear..I think. I can see the wirdness I cannot forget. The multiplication of functions at one point gives me infinity muled by number. Which I cannot get or understand right now, this is good enough though. So many thanks @Winther! I will use your advice and skip to pure formula learning tomorrow, when I back to learning. Many thanks!